# How to resolve Persistent-memory address?

Tags: linux-kernel

When developing a file system for Optane DC PM, how do I differentiate between DRAM addresses and PMEM addresses?

e.g.) File system is a kind of OS kernel code. When file system code is executed, how can the code understand byte-addressable PMEM address, separating with DRAM address.

### Is it logically adjacent?
Such like,

### |DRAM                 |NVM(PMEM)                       |

0x0000                500G                             1.25T

Comment: *"how do I differentiate between DRAM addresses and PMEM addresses?"* -- I would hope that such information is provided to the kernel as board configuration data, e.g. using Device Tree nodes.  Or are you thinking of using a probe routine?  BTW for a *"file system for XXX"*, you would first need a "block device" and its driver.  RAM (volatile or not) is normally handled as "memory" which is *uninitialized* except for known addresses holding kernel text & data (including initfs), data passed by a bootloader (e.g. DeviceTree & cpio/tar archive), and ramdisk.

Comment: I've worked on something similar: battery-backed SRAM.  Despite the promise of performance just like main memory, IMO the storage pitfalls are (1) need to verify the integrity of the contents on startup, and (2) need to recover from power-cuts (i.e. incomplete sequence of writes).  Therefore the overhead of a ramdisk as described in **Documentation/filesystems/ramfs-rootfs-initramfs.rst** could be impossible to avoid, that is, can a persistent memory storage use the optimizations of a tmpfs?

Comment: ㄴ Thanks for your reply! PMEM is byte-addressable media, so I think that the persistent memory storage doesn't use the optimizations of a tmpfs. But  as I am not sure about this, I should check it more.